# How to use setInputMethod in InputMethodManager class

Tags: android

Given this code below :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> inputMethods = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
for(InputMethodInfo method : inputMethods){
    String name = method.loadLabel(activity.getPackageManager()).toString();
    new InfoDialog(activity,name).show();
    //imm.setInputMethod(token, id);
}
```

I have two **Input Method** installed in my device: **Samsung Keyboard** and **Google Handwriting Input**. What I was trying to do is to switch between these two **Keyboards** using `setInputMethod`.

Example:

```
imm.setInputMethod(<Samsung Keyboard>);
```

or

```
imm.setInputMethod(<Google Handwriting Input>);
```

**How to do it?  Any Idea?**

Answer (score 4):

umm no way to change it passively, instead prompt user to do that

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

However if you had system privilege then you could change it like :

```
Settings.Secure.putString(resolver, Settings.Secure.ENABLED_INPUT_METHODS, "com.package.to.keyboard/.full.path");
Settings.Secure.putString(resolver, Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD, "com.package.to.keyboard/.full.path");
```

Comment: lets say you have a menu in your UI each item representing your installed keyboards. on the menu item click you will change the keyboards and hence put the codes there. Its your application dependent really.